# Mysql: Connection refused ERROR: 111

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I can't connect to my server when I use a remote IP address.

Localhost is working fine.

**Some info:**

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Database: MariaDB

Port 3306 is open

User has remote (%) access.

I've changed bind-address in 50-server.conf to bind-address = 0.0.0.0 and I tried commenting it out. none of them worked. Also tried putting bind-address = 0.0.0.0in my.conf under a [mysqld] grouptag. After every change I restarted Mysql and tried to connect with this command mrsql -u root -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p. It works fine for localhost, but does not work when I try my servers IP.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is "50-server.conf"?

Comment: Exactly what error message do you get in each case?  (This could be a `GRANT` problem.)

Comment: when I looking in `my.conf` I saw nothing but a couple includes. Including `50-server.conf` in that folder I found the `bind-address` line. I changed that. but it did not work. But I now got it working after some time.

Answer (score 1):

After days of surfing and trying all the solutions given in stackoverflow, I finally managed to establish connection to mysql or Mariadb remotely.

Here is the solution for accessing mysql db from a remote machine:

Firstly, In your /etc/my.cnf or whatever location my.cnf is located in your machine:

```
bind-address= THE_HOST_IP_ON_WHICH_MYSQLDB_IS_INSTALLED
# skip-networking ( This will allow TCP/IP connection)
```

Secondly, Make sure there is no ip's in /etc/hosts.deny ( This can be root cause for connection in many cases)

```
> Important:
> 1. restart mysqld = systemctl restart mysqld ( Ubuntu might have diff cmd)
> 2. check status = systemctl status mysqld ( Ubuntu might have diff cmd)
> 3. check port and ip on which mysqld is running = netstat -tlnp  It should be running on THE_HOST_IP_ON_WHICH_MYSQLDB_IS_INSTALLED: 3306  ( Ubuntu might have diff cmd)
```

Thirdly, Create a user with ALL privileges like :

```
> GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO username@THE_HOST_IP_ON_WHICH_MYSQLDB_IS_INSTALLED IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

LASTLY,  if using workbench or any other client to establish connection. Enter values as:

```
> HOSTNAME= THE_HOST_IP_ON_WHICH_MYSQLDB_IS_INSTALLED 
>username=username
```

I hope this helps any of my fellow users!